# WorkerLostError, Python.exe APPCRASH with django/celery under Windows

Tags: windows, django, celery

I have Django set up under Windows (Win2008 Server R2, IIS 7.5, MS SQL). I'm trying to implement celery 2.4.1 (with RabbitMQ) for task processing and running into a very frustrating problem.

I start celeryd with the recommended:

```
manage.py celeryd --settings=settings
```

and it runs OK. Then in my django project, I trigger a task to start (for testing I'm just using the simple "add" example:

```
@task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

and that's called in my views.py as:

```
tasks.add.delay(1,2)
```

When celeryd picks this up, a couple of things happen, *sometimes*:
1) I get a Windows dialog, "python.exe has stopped working", and an option to close it.
2) After closing that, in the cmd where celeryd is running, I get:

```
[date-time: ERROR/MainProcess] Task [taskUUID] raised exception: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\processes\pool.py", line 610, in _join_exited_workers
    raise WorkerLostError("Worker exited prematurely.")
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely.
```

I've tried very tediously tinkering with just about every celery setting, one at a time, that could possibly affect workers (CELERYD_CONCURRENCY, CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER, CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD, etc.) with no effect whatsoever on this.

What's really strange is that sometimes, after that has happened (and I just leave celeryd running...it doesn't kill that process...?), I can trigger the task again, with no python.exe crash, and the task will complete successfully.

My celery-relevant settings from settings.py:

```
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "guest"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "guest"
BROKER_VHOST = "/"

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("myproject.tasks",)
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"

CELERY_SEND_EVENTS=True #same as '-E' option from cmd
```

I strongly suspect a celery bug (possibly specific to Windows implementation?) but I don't quite have the chops yet to identify it or propose a fix.

Comment: Any findings with this? I'm stuck with the same problem with redis as the borker.

Comment: I'm still getting WorkerLostErrors, but I've found a workaround...I was tinkering around and discovered that if I queued up a large number of tasks (>> numberOfWorkers*concurrency), the first 'n' tasks would fail, but subsequent tasks would succeed. So it's basically like the workers need a "kick" of some sort. In my specific case, I have 2 workers with concurrency of 2. If I send at least 8 tasks, I can get over the hump. I've set up a simple "DummyTask" that does nothing at all, specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after many months of tinkering on and off with this, I believe I have figured it out.

The problem appears to be coming from the use of django-mssql as the Django database engine. django-mssql relies on pywin32, and one of the calls there uses ole32.dll and causes a crash there, which consequently brings down Python, hence the WorkerLostError.

I've switched to django-pyodbc which does not use the problematic pywin32/ole32.dll call, and have not experienced an unexplained WorkerLostError such as these since switching.